# How to specify jar export directory on vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar, export

I want to know if I can specify a special directory for the "Export jar" option on Vscode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest version (0.14.0) of **Project Manager for Java** extension, it introduced a new setting `java.project.exportJar.targetPath` to specify the output location of the export jar. By default, it's `${workspaceFolder}/${workspaceFolderBasename}.jar`

You can also set it empty, which means the extension will prompt a file explorer dialog to ask you choose the location.